# Set variable value depending on mod

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to set `browse-url-browser-funciton` depending on which mod is active for a buffer. This is specifically meant to have `pylookup` open documentation with w3m and org-mode open links with firefox (when on X11).

At the moment I just have this in my .emacs:

`(setq browse-url-browser-function 'w3m-browse-url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a local value for that variable depending on the major mode, by adding a function to the mode hook.  Something like:

```
(defun use-firefox ()
  (set (make-local-variable 'browse-url-browser-function) 'browse-url-firefox))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'use-firefox)
```

That would use Firefox for links opened in org-mode buffers, and the default value for all other buffers.  (Note that it only applies to newly opened buffers.)